# Are there two inode tables used in locating the inode of a file in ext2?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext2

From Tanenbaum's Modern Operating Systems, when trying to access a file in a ext2 file system in Linux, and then reaching the parent directory of the file,

> If the file is present, the system extracts the i-node number and uses it as an
>   index into **the i-node table** (on disk) to locate the corresponding i-node and bring it
>   into  memory. The  i-node  is  put  in  **the i-node  table**, a kernel  data  structure  that
>   holds all the i-nodes for currently open files and directories.

Are there two different inode tables mentioned?

1. Is the first inode table stored somewhere in the disk? Where is it
   stored? See the layout of a disk, a partition, and a file system below from the same book.

   Is it a mapping from the inode numbers to the inode addresses?
2. Is the second inode table stored in the main memory?

   Is it a mapping from what to the inodes?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The text you quoted is, arguably, sloppily worded. 
The master, authoritative inodes for a filesystem
are stored in the filesystem. 
So, for a filesystem that’s on a disk (in a disk partition),
the inodes are on the disk.  But, for efficiency,
the kernel stores (caches) local copies of active inodes in memory.

1. To repeat, yes, “the first inode table” is stored on the disk
   (assuming that the filesystem is disk-resident).  So what are you asking? 
   The two figures you copied into your question
   both show areas labeled “I-nodes”.  Those are where the inodes are. 
   The specifics are different in different filesystem types.

   - Is it a mapping from the inode numbers to the inode addresses?
     No; the inodes are stored in an array
     (or, in some filesystems, in several arrays),
     so the inode address can be computed by a formula that looks something like

     > inode address = (base address of inode array) + (inode number) × (sizeof inode)

   As I hope you already know, an inode *contains* the metadata for a file,
   and it *points to* the data blocks for the file.
2. Yes, “the second inode table” is stored in memory. 
   It’s not a mapping to the inodes;
   it’s a *copy* of selected inodes (with, perhaps,
   some additional metadata concerning the state of the inode in the system).